# How to avoid warning 8618 in razor control when using CascadingParameter?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

I receive a cascading parameter inside a razor control. This is the Authentificaction State.

```
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }
```

But this line raise a warning (CS8618)

> Non-nullable property 'authenticationStateTask ' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

Since this is a Taks, the null forgiving operator (!) doesn't work.

How I can avoid this warnign?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701187/avoid-cs8618-warning-when-initializing-mutable-non-nullable-property-with-argume), they use the `#pragma warning disable CS8618` to avoid this. But I thinks it should be a better way to avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the null forgiving approach it does work:

```
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; } = default!;
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions for you after you updated your question:

Try to make it nullable:

```
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask? { get; set; }
```

Otherwise try adding the following code to the component:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
    authenticationStateTask = new Task<AuthenticationState>();
}
```

Comment: The nullable idea doesn´t work, Task cannot be nullable... The second idea would suppres the cascadingparameter info, that is coming, but that let me a new idea... maybe there is somewhere else in the execution tree on the component that I can use to define it, before the parent change it...

Comment: In that case, you could do it in OnParamatersSet instead of OnInitializedAsync after checking if a value was passed in

Comment: The "?" should go after the type, not the property name: `Task<AuthenticationState>?` - that works fine as long as you first check for (not) null before awaiting it

Comment: Nullable reference is also used in M$ documentation  [ASP.NET Core Blazor authentication and authorization  - Procedural logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#procedural-logic)